# Does Acumatica Report Designer have this feature?

Tags: acumatica

Does Acumatica Report Designer have this feature ??

In the Stock Item Description user entered text along with uploaded pictures / photographs in Acumatica.

How do I print the same in Report Designer ??

I included a Picture Box and modified the type as text/hmtl the text got printed on the Report. However Images in the Stock Item description which are updated in the Uploaded file table are available. How do they get placed in the report ??

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, report engine does not allow verbatim html due to security reasons.